# Grid view refreshing

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have used below code for delete command  of GridView, but when I press delete command , the data in grid view will not be refreshed, actually command deletes the row but grid view does not update. I have to refresh manually browser then grid view will be update.
Markup:

```
<div>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>



<asp:GridView ID="GridViewDocuments_Search" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns=False 
          Visible="False" onrowcommand="GridViewDocuments_Search_RowCommand"  
  DataKeyNames="DocID" PageSize="100" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True"  >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Details">
           <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID ="btn_Show" Text="Details" runat= "server" CommandName= "Details" CommandArgument='<%#
        Container.DataItemIndex%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentNo" HeaderText="DocNo" />


        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Docid" HeaderText="Docid" Visible="false" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>

  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The code:

```
protected void GridViewDocuments_Search_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();

    int _Docid = (int)GridViewDocuments_Search.DataKeys[rowindex].Value;

     switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Details":
           Response.Redirect("~/Documentfortest.aspx?DocID=" + _Docid);
            break;
        case "Delete":
            _DataContext.DeleteDoc(_Docid);

            break;

    }

 var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);

     GridViewDocuments_Search.DataSource = query;
     GridViewDocuments_Search.DataBind();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you re-assign the `DataSource` property before you call `DataBind` and then try ?

Comment: i re-assign datasource to gridview but not updating/refreshing yet gridview var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);
         
         GridViewDocuments_Search.DataSource = query;

Comment: Just wanted to confirm whether you called `DataBind` after you re-assign data source ? Also does the new data source contain the deleted row ? Ideally, it should not. Do you see any Javascript errors ? such as timeouts or other ?